# Make Flask Web App in Raspberry Pi Available on Internet

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, ip, raspberry-pi3, dhcp

Currently the Flask app is available via other devices on same network. This helps me to access the app via other device from same network.

```
app.run(port=80, host='0.0.0.0')
```

I want it to be available for all/worldwide. I sent the Mac Address of wlan0 from my RPi and asked the ISP provider to give me an Static IP (Paid), which they given me. Now, I don't know what to do.

I given them wlan0 MAC address: b8:27:eb:96:8b:bf

The information my provider given to me are below:

Assigned M-DHCP IPs as follows:

IP address: 10.185.151.74

DHCP type: M-DHCP

Object class: PC

Subnet: 10.185.151.0/21  (VLAN 2083)

Answer (score 0):

Public IP address is assigned only to your router, Raspberry Pi has still local (LAN) IP address.

You must make port forwarding in your router/firewall.

You must forward port 80 to the local IP address of your Raspberry Pi